# Resize the middle partition of an .img file

Tags: linux, command-line, partition

I want to resize the partitions of my `.img` file. (The `.img` file will be flashed later on a SD Card.) The .img file consists of three partitions:

```
| ~ 100 MB boot | ~ 1 GB linux | ~ 6 GB data |
```

My aim is to increase the linux partition by about 1 GB and shrink the data partition also by 1 GB. My thought was to shrink first the data partition and then move it to the right. Then I wanted to increase the linux partition.

Shrinking worked with the `parted` tool, but there is no move function included in `parted` anymore. So I was not able to move the data partition to the right.

If you know an easier solution to increase the middle partition, I would be grateful if you can explain it to me.

The main problem is that it needs to be done via CLI (it's not possible to use a graphical tools like `gparted`).

Comment: I understand you can't use gparted on the final target. But can't you copy a sample of the `.img` file to a machine having gparted ? Looking at the details once all changes have been applied will basically give you the recipe to script that yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The .img file is delivered by a partner of us. I need to add some additional tools to the .img. This steps - downloading the .img file, resizing the partitions and adding additional tools to the .img - should be done in an automated way. That's is the reason why I need a script. 
But if it doesn't work with skripts well, then I will have no choice to do it manually with gparted.

Comment: My point was: if you do it once manually with gparted and look at the details after the different steps have been applied (the list can even be saved as an html file on your disk...), you basically have all the calculations/commands that were taken to acheive the result. From there, it's quite easy to write a script.

Comment: Thank you! This worked fine for me. Unfortunately there were no commands for shrinking/moving the partition itself in the logs (There were only the commands for shrinking the filesystem), but I found a link where it was perfectly explained.
[link](https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-shrinking-ext4-partition-on-command-line/)

Answer (score 0):

I want to summarize how the problem is now solved.
First I did the resizing/moving once with gparted to get the values for resizing/moving and to get the exact steps that are performed. The values and steps are stored in gparted logs.

Following steps are executed:

```
# Check file system 
sudo e2fsck -f -y -v -C 0 "/dev/loop18p3"

# Resize filesystem
sudo resize2fs -p "/dev/loop18p3" 5038080K

# Resize partition 
# This step is not included in the logs of gparted
# I used fdisk for resizing partition

(
echo d
echo 3
echo n
echo 3
echo 2367488
echo 12443647
echo w
) | sudo fdisk /dev/loop18

# Move filesystem to the right
sudo e2image -ra -p -O 1073741824 "/dev/loop18p3"

The further steps are basically the same. The only differences are the values.
```

Thanks to @Zeitounator for the hint to use gparted logs!